# Why does this not stop my character from jumping unlimited times?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My character just jumps continuously even in the air, I'm not sure why the boolean does not stop it and I cannot figure it out. This is what I have so far:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    bool spacePressed = false;
    float upForce = 200f;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            spacePressed = false;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("space") && spacePressed == false)
        {
            spacePressed = true;
            rb.AddForce(0, upForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that 'space pressed' is never or instantly set to false. So a first step on debuging it can be to watch the boolean. You can do that with 'public ...'. Then you should just observe when it's set to true/false.

There is also the possiblilty of this being a totally different kind of issue. For instance that one of the colliders could be of the wrong size (too big/small)

And to complete the holy trinity: There is a free 2D platformer example in the unity hub. I think they use a different approche by using an empty GO as a 'isGrounded' checker. One of the first things I learned as a hobbist is not to be ashamed to copy code of example projects.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the collider is hitting `Obstacle` as it makes its first jump. `OnCollisionEnter` is **very unreliable** when checking if an object is beside/on another object. This can be checked if you use `Debug.Log` and check to see how much times it randomly activates `OnCollisionEnter`.

To reliably check if an object is beside another object use [raycasts](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) or [boxcasts](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.BoxCast.html) instead.

This is some code that should work that uses *raycasts*:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Collider collider;
    public float extraCheckHeight = 0.1f;

    float upForce = 200f;

    bool isGrounded(){
        Physics2D.Raycast(collider.bounds.center, Vector3.down, collider.bounds.extents.y + extraCheckHeight);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("space") && isGrounded)
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, upForce, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);//Time.deltaTime is should not be here because it should be the same force regardless of the time between frames
        }
    }
}
```

This should do the trick but I recommend researching about unity raycasts and boxcasts.
Here is a video on Ground Checking that I found useful when I was approached with a similar problem: [Ground Check](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3iEl5AwUF8)